# How can I print a date/time from time::strftime without leading zeros?

Tags: time, rust, strftime

How can I print a date/time without leading zeros? For example, `Jul 5, 9:15`.

According to the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/time/time/index.html) it uses the same syntax as `strftime`, however suppressing leading zeros

```
time::strftime("%b %-d, %-I:%M", &time::now()).unwrap()
```

leads to an error:

> thread '' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: InvalidFormatSpecifier('-')', ../src/libcore/result.rs:746

I suspect Rust doesn't support the glibc extensions that provide this flag (and several others); however there is no syntax for non-prefixed date/time; the alternative (`%l`) just prefixes with blank space which is equally useless.

I could create the string by hand, but that defeats the purpose of the function.

Comment: I think the [chrono crate](https://lifthrasiir.github.io/rust-chrono/chrono/format/strftime/index.html) has support for that specifier.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looking [the code](https://github.com/rust-lang-deprecated/time/blob/0.1.35/src/lib.rs#L602-L641) we can confirm that `time` crate does not support the flag `-`.

---

That said, I recommend you use the [`chrono`](https://crates.io/crates/chrono) crate. In addition to supporting the format specifiers you want, the chrono crate also has support for timezones and much more.

```
let now = chrono::Utc::now();
println!("{}", now.format("%b %-d, %-I:%M").to_string());
```

Comment: I'm getting "Could not find `UTC` in `chrono`" when using this code.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Figured it out, `UTC` is actually `Utc`